# Is there a way to use Canvas in IE7 or IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas

Is there any workaround to use "Canvas" tag in IE7 and IE8 ?
Pls let me know.

```
<input type="text" id="textSign" value="Sign" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:return changeSign();" value="changeSign" />
<canvas id="e" width="150" height="100"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var textSign = document.getElementById("textSign").value;
      function changeSign() {
             textSign = document.getElementById("textSign").value;
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    context.fillStyle = "#4c4c4c";
                    context.font = "30px Giddyup Std";
                    context.fillText (textSign , 20, 50);
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, there is a project to *simulate* the canvas API on older versions of IE (7 and 8).

You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/), simply include the JavaScript file and go on as canvas was supported.

Please note that is another layer of JavaScript code on the top of IE (and it's not famous to be very fast to parse JavaScript...)

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer because I hadn't tested it. Is that complete and fast (if so that's probably a better answer than mine) ?

Comment: @dystroy it's pretty complete (at least for what I tried I didn't find any missing feature) but it's not fast at all (after all it's another layer so it can't be faster than native support, moreover IE isn't a rabbit regarding JavaScript speed...)

Comment: @Richa take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=69

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is : https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

But as with any modern web technology, you'll have to make extensive tests while developping. And depending on your deployement location, you may be forbidden to use that (sysadmins still imposing IE7 may have strange requirements).

Comment: hey,
Is this the only way to support canvas in IE, as I cannot compel user to go somewhere else and download chrome frame.

Comment: Test Adriano's solution too. It may be easier to use. But of course it's hard to combine modern technologies with IE7. In at least one case I found easier to propose chrome-frame to my (corporate) users as a transition technology.

Comment: Just a heads up: As of June 2013 google has retired Chrome-frame. You might be able to find an installer somewhere out there but it might not be able to be installed via ActiveX as in previous versions.

Answer (score -1):

No. 
Canvas element is supported only in IE9.